# Unable to extract video from pcapng, saved wireshark files

Tags: video, video-streaming, wireshark, rtmp, pcap-ng

I'm trying to extract/save video from live video streaming using wireshark. I'm able to store/get rtmpt data packets however, I'm unable to extract video from those data packets...

1. Is there any way to extract video from pcapng files?
2. Can I directly extract video while live streaming?

Comment: How is this a **programming** question? Otherwise it's **off-topic** for this forum. Read [**How To Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you don't understand how this website works..

Comment: Well programmers like me and you have to work on several applications, and wireshark like many others is a must have tool for a programmer for debugging and all that stuff... hope that explains things